# Swift parsing JSON, nested array

Tags: json, swift, nested

```
{
 "def": [
    {
      "sseq": [
        [
          [
             "sense",
           {
             "sn": "1",
             "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}a set of the equipment used in a particular activity {bc}{sx|gear||} "
                ],
                [
                  "vis",
                  [
                    {
                      "t": "fishing {wi}tackle{/wi}"
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[jsonFormat](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b876f678660f4a1698e146d45131d2a4)

I am having trouble parsing this JSON, with the nested arrays. I am trying to get to the definition under "text" in "dt". The current output is something like this, while I am just trying to get to the definition:

```
["text", "{bc}to emit puffs (as of breath or steam)"]
["text", "{bc}to make empty threats {bc}{sx|bluster||}"]
["text", "{bc}to react or behave indignantly"]
```

```
 for result in jsonArray {
                        if let def = result["def"] as? JsonArray {
                            for defItem in def {
                                //print(defItem)
                                if let sseq = defItem["sseq"] as? [Any] {
                                    for _1 in sseq {
                                        if let _1arr = _1 as? [Any] {
                                            for _2 in _1arr {
                                                if let _2arr = _2 as? [Any] {
                                                    for _3 in _2arr {
                                                        if let res = _3 as? JsonDict {
                                                            if let definitions = res["dt"] as? [[String]] {

                                                                print(definitions[0])

                                                            }
```

Comment: ` am trying to get to the definition under "text" in "dt"` There is no 'definition' under 'text'. 'text' is the first string in the array, and the blurb is the second string. Are you saying you want to get a list of those second strings?

Also, where do `JsonArray` and `JsonDict` come from? how did you get to some object from string? (e.g. Codable/NSJsonSerialization/SwiftyJSON etc.)

Comment: Look into Swift's `Codable` protocol. That JSON is seriously FUBAR'd though. If possible, I'd really recommend trying to fix that first.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the second string. JsonDict and JsonArray:                                                   typealias JsonDict = [String:Any]
typealias JsonArray = [JsonDict]

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert pointed out, this JSON is in a bad place. As a fun thought exercise here's what you can do.

Formatted json:

```
{
   "def":[
      {
         "sseq":[
            [
               [
                  "sense",
                  {
                     "sn":"1",
                     "dt":[
                        [
                           "text",
                           "{bc}a set of the equipment used in a particular activity {bc}{sx|gear||} "
                        ],
                        [
                           "vis",
                           [
                              {
                                 "t":"fishing {wi}tackle{/wi}"
                              }
                           ]
                        ]
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            ]
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Meet Swift Codable:

```
let woah = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Woah.self, from: jsonData)

// MARK: - Woah
struct Woah {
    let def: [Def]
}

// MARK: - Def
struct Def {
    let sseq: [[[SseqElement]]]
}

enum SseqElement {
    case sseqClass(SseqClass)
    case string(String)
}

// MARK: - SseqClass
struct SseqClass {
    let sn: String
    let dt: [[DtUnion]]
}

enum DtUnion {
    case dtClassArray([DtClass])
    case string(String)
}

// MARK: - DtClass
struct DtClass {
    let t: String
}
```

Comment: For all the `enum` cases with associatedtype, you need to implement initializer to parse the respective value and initialize `enum` accordingly. Also `newJSONDecoder()` should be `JSONDecoder()`.